# How to use java jar within php exec() to run on putty

Tags: php, putty

On putty when i run java jar  code separate it work properly and when use it within php script exec command it give error java command not found
please tell me if have any idea about this
thanks

Comment: Can you please give the code and the output?

Comment: this is code   <?php

function convert_pdfTotext_File($pdfFileName, $TextFileName) {

    exec('java -jar "home/life/public_html/system/crons/canadalife/pdf_java/java_jar/PDFReader-1.0.jar" ./pdf_java/' . $pdfFileName . 'home/life/public_html/system/crons/canadalife/pdf_java/text/' . $TextFileName . '.txt');
}
?>

Comment: and output is as below  login as: root

[root@host ~]# cd ..
[root@host /]# cd home
[root@host home]# cd life
[root@host life]# cd public_html
[root@host public_html]# cd system
[root@host system]# cd crons
[root@host crons]# cd canadalife
[root@host canadalife]# php getpolicyData.php

sh: java: command not found
Array
(
)
Universal Life Insurance Summary<br>
[root@host canadalife]#

Comment: use fullpath then try it again

Comment: no run from project folder canadalife